# Pros and cons for serving web content directly from an Azure storage account

Tags: azure, azure-storage, azure-storage-files

I'm thinking about setting up 2 web VMs with a load balancer and availability set, and another VM for SQL server (not sure if I can set an availability set for a SQL Server as well - SQL Server Express / Standard?)

My main problem is how to keep both web servers in sync (prefer not to use the DFS) or having the files in more than one location...

Another issue - is user uploaded content that I want to be available in both web servers (I wonder if I can also direct cache objects to be saved on a specific storage disk)

So, I was thinking to setup a storage account and attach it to both web VMs for user uploaded content and images while each server still serve it's own separate web application with same shared access to content files...

Is that a good idea? I understand that Azure storage is a virtual disk that is supposed to be highly available and fast - is it true??

Do I get a major performance hit if using the same storage disk from 3 different VMs (is that even possible?)

**UPDATE:**

I found out that because I'm using the BizSpark program I can't really connect more than one server - and share resources between them (unless I pay extra for it). so this became irrelevant for now

Also, I'm talking about ASP.NET but this shouldn't matter

Comment: You have multiple questions here, and none of them programming-related (and "is it a good idea" is opinion-based). Sharing content between VMs will require you to either sync data or store data external to the VMs (such as Azure storage which you asked about). Azure Storage is *not* a virtual disk, but vhd's are stored in Azure Storage. Regarding Azure Storage performance: That's all [documented here](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/storage-scalability-targets/).

Comment: I'm with Dave. You are talking about your overall strategy, which is several questions. Try to focus them.  This is a Q & A forum, not a Reddit AMA. :-) Also, please detail what technologies you are using, as that would help with these questions. ASP.NET? Node.js? Ruby?  I would also encourage you to use Azure's PaaS offerings (Azure SQL, Web Apps, etc) whenever possible instead of IaaS (virtual machines). As for caching, look into Redis Cache. I can't provide better answers without more information.

Answer (score 0):

Azure Files enables you to run multiple IIS instances against a single file share and thus not have to worry about replicating files across the multiple shares - so this is definitely an option. See [Getting Started with File Storage](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/storage-dotnet-how-to-use-files/) for more information.